# My figure is floating to a new page after the header. Any ideas?

Tags: floats

I'm trying to insert a new section into my document, which should essentially just be a figure with a footnote (it's an image of a time plan for the project being worked on). However, when I use the code as shown below, the header appears, but then leaves an entire page open before inserting the image. I've tried making the image smaller, but with the parameters as shown below it should have MORE than enough space to fit in the required area. Any ideas?

```
\section{Project Timeline}
Typetype
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=12cm]{TimePlan1}
  \caption{The proposed project timeline}\label{TimePlan1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal working code that encapsulates the problem? Throwing what you have posted into a document works for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome, you have used just the right term. The figure is *floating* around, cause you tell it to do by using the *floating* `figure` environment. Please have a look at [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: You probably want `\begin{figure}[htp]` (without `h` it will never come at that point in the document)

Comment: David, you, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. That fixed the problem. What exactly did that modifier do? 
Johannes_B, thanks for the link. I'm reading up on it now, it's already helping a lot.